# How to know if javascript lib is still used in a website?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, structure, dead-code

I'm working on a website which is quite a mess. In the `<head>` of the website about a zillion javascript libraries are loaded and I think many of them are not used anymore. The problem is that I'm not sure.

In Python (my language of choice) there are always clear namespaces and using a capable Python editor (such as Pycharm) clearly highlights unused imports. I'm looking for something similar in html/javascript.

I can of course start writing a comprehensive set of UI-tests (which I should do anyway), but that is something for a later stage. I first want to clean up the code a bit and speed up loading time.

Does anybody know (a preferably simple way) how I can find out if a library loaded in `<head>` is still used anywhere on the website?

Comment: Remove some and see if console starts to complain? I'm also curious about this, that even if you use something like `requireJs` to manage deps, its still hard to detect dead codes in my experience..

Comment: Since linked scripts may simply be doing something by themselves, as opposed to being used by something, it's basically impossible to tell without trial and error.

Comment: this is quasi impossible without a long very long and hard work ! You have to test any use case you can have ! can you ? maybe you have a script used once in specific situation, could you see it ? reach it ? maybe some rewrite will be more benefict.

Comment: As stated in most other comments that's nearly impossible. You can modify the library, and flood it with `console.error()` in strategic places, specially in code that is directly executed: blocks of code, self executed functions, and so on. If there are errors you can see them clearly in the console. If you take into account that JS is not typed, and is dynamic, I think that finding a tool for this is impossible. For example is nearly impossible to detect that a library is necessary because it modifies or includes new properties in exiting objects,like a jQuery plugin.