# How to debug angular library error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'm using Angular in a website in which I just upgraded `angular`, `angular-route` and `angular-ui-router` to the latest bower versions. But suddenly I get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: a.remove is not a function
    at Object.H.removeListener (main.js:7)
    at Object.b.module.service.a.removeEvents (angular-google-maps.min.js?version=2.2.1:5)
    at angular-google-maps.min.js?version=2.2.1:8
    at n.a.$get.n.$broadcast (angular.js:16311)
    at n.a.$get.n.$destroy (angular.js:15923)
    at j (angular-ui-router.min.js?version=0.2.15:7)
    at angular-ui-router.min.js?version=0.2.15:7
    at angular.js:7554
    at k (angular-ui-router.min.js?version=0.2.15:7)
    at angular-ui-router.min.js?version=0.2.15:7
```

The problem is now that I'm unsure of how to debug this. In the trace above I see two libs: [angular-ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) and [angular-google-maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/). Should I start looking through the source of these libs, or is there something I'm missing in this trace which shows me how to solve this?

All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
As suggested in the comments by @charlietfl I checked the dependencies of angular-google-maps in the bower.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2 - 1.4",
    "angular-simple-logger": "~0.0.1",
    "lodash": ">=3.8.0"
},
```

Currently I've got:

- angular version 1.4.7
- angular-simple-logger version 0.0.4
- lodash version 3.10.1

From this only `angular-simple-logger` seems to be off. But I'm unsure what to do from here. Should I downgrade `angular-simple-logger` to version 0.0.1, should I change `"~0.0.1",` to `">=0.0.1",` or is there anything else I could do?

Comment: check comparability of angular-maps

Comment: @charlietfl - I added the dependencies of angular-google-maps and the versions of those dependencies I'm on. Any idea how to proceed from here?

Comment: *"upgraded angular, angular-route and angular-ui-router"* Do you really need both `ui-router` and `angular-route` in the same app?

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos - I'm not even sure, but stuff works now, and since there doesn't seem to be an easy way of knowing if dependencies are still needed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145094/how-to-know-if-javascript-lib-is-still-used-in-a-website), I don't want to risk it right now. In my app.js I only use `$stateProvider` and `$urlRouterProvider` though. Should I remove one of the two dependencies?

Comment: These two are from `ui-router`, you can remove `angular-route`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your source code, so this looks like it might be pretty specific to your application. Especially with `ui-router`, state parameters can muck up a lot of things.

If this were my application, I would first turn these settings on in the Chrome debugger.

[image]

Then I would run the code and step through until the exception was thrown in `angular-ui-router.min.js`, since that's furthest back in the stack trace.

To make things readable, you click this handy button:

[image: Make things pretty button]

It might not be the quickest solution, but it will get you the details you need to further diagnose the problem.